# problems with correct update to .net 4.0 on win2003

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, asp.net-4.0

Tried to test .net4rc1 site on test host with win2003. As expected by default server returned error about " targetFramework="4.0" in web.config. But since I switched ASP.NET version to 4.0 and reboot that site just returning 404.

Whats wrong?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found answer [here](http://johan.driessen.se/archive/2010/04/13/getting-an-asp.net-4-application-to-work-on-iis6.aspx).

> Well, it turns out that just because you install .NET 4 on Windows 2003 Server, you’re not automatically allowed to use it i IIS! 
>   ...
>   Just run the following command: cscript iisext.vbs /EnFile C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll